# ASP.NET MVC cookies not saving?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies

Why doesn't this cookie save in the Session_Start method of my global.asax?

```
//new anon user:

var authCookie = new HttpCookie("user-id", string.Format("{0}-{1}", regiserAccountResponse.UserName, regiserAccountResponse.Key))
{
    Expires = DateTime.MaxValue,
    Domain = "domain.com",
    Secure = true,
    HttpOnly = true
};

//create the new users cookie - there's no need to call RegisterNewUserSession as this is done in the same call
HttpContext.Current.Response.SetCookie(authCookie);
```

Comment: How are you detecting whether it's actually saved? Have you used Wireshark to see whether it's coming down? Have you fixed the domain and secure bits to reflect reality?

Comment: should i leave domain blank until i'm ready to deploy? or should it be localhost until i deploy?

Comment: Try removing it entirely. It's not like you're really serving "domain.com" is it? I can't say I know much about cookies, but those settings definitely look wrong...

Comment: thanks jon - remd the secure and domain props and it seems to work now - if you add that to an answer i'll mark it correct :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You only need to specify the Domain if you want to limit the cookie to a specific section of your website. The cookie will only be included in the request if it is in the correct scope.

By setting the Domain to "domain.com", you are saying that the cookie will only be available to "domain.com", so you won't detect it from localhost (or from any other domain other than domain.com").

You will also notice that if you try and send a browser a cookie from a domain other than your own, the browser will bin it.

Comment: Thanks steve! Both right - looks like it's working now so all good in da hood... :)

Comment: Svet svet baby. Hope the new job is sound.

Answer (score 0):

iOS is now pretty keen to bin domainless cookies asap, so while the accepted answer says "You only need to specify the Domain if you want to limit the cookie to a specific section of your website" - I don't think this is true. You need to set a domain.

The following snippet will work from local through to production:

```
    private static HttpCookie CreateCookie(string name, string value)
    {
        return new HttpCookie(name, value) { Path = "/", Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(1), Domain = Request.Url.Host };
    }
```