# ASP.NET MVC 5 - Cookies being not created

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, asp.net-mvc-5

I am having my controller action that calls a private method that handles a cookie. The problem is that the cookie is not being created at all. I read multiple posts on SO but I haven't found an answer as I think that my handling cookies in this code is correct.

Is there any web.config setting that I need to check in regards to cookies? I also tried different browsers.

I debugged the code and I can see that the cookie is actually set in the code but as soon as I load the page and have a look at cookies the cookie is not there.

```
  private ABHomeModel HandleWhiteBoxCookie(ABHomeModel model)
        {
            var whiteBox = _whiteBoxService.GetActiveWhiteBox();

            if (model.WhiteBox != null)
            {
                const string cookieName = "whiteBox";

                var whiteBoxCookie = HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Get(cookieName);

                if (whiteBoxCookie != null)
                {
                    var displayedTimes = Convert.ToInt32(whiteBoxCookie.Value);
                    if (displayedTimes < 2)
                    {
                        displayedTimes++;

                        var cookie = new HttpCookie(cookieName, displayedTimes.ToString())
                        {
                            Expires = new DateTime().AddMonths(1),
                            Secure = false
                        };

                        HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);
                        ViewBag.IsWhiteBoxActive = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ViewBag.IsWhiteBoxActive = false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    var cookie = new HttpCookie(cookieName, "1")
                    {
                        HttpOnly = true,
                        Domain = Request.Url.Host,
                        Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1),
                        Secure = false
                    };

                    HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
                    ViewBag.IsWhiteBoxActive = true;
                }

                model.WhiteBox = whiteBox;
            }

            return model;
        }
```

Comment: try capture the traffic and see what the response looks like

Comment: Steve Fenton's explained this pretty well in this post.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/4285929/4216075

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My colleague found the issue. It is in regard to setting the domain. As soon as we removed this line:

```
Domain = Request.Url.Host,
```

The cookies started working and are now being created.

The full updated code of the method:

```
private ABHomeModel HandleWhiteBoxCookie(ABHomeModel model)
        {
            var whiteBox = _whiteBoxService.GetActiveWhiteBox();

            if (whiteBox != null)
            {
                const string cookieName = "whiteBox";

                var whiteBoxCookie = HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Get(cookieName);

                if (whiteBoxCookie != null)
                {
                    var displayedTimes = Convert.ToInt32(whiteBoxCookie.Value);
                    if (displayedTimes < 2)
                    {
                        displayedTimes++;

                        var cookie = new HttpCookie(cookieName, displayedTimes.ToString())
                        {
                            HttpOnly = true,
                            Secure = false
                        };

                        HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);
                        ViewBag.IsWhiteBoxActive = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ViewBag.IsWhiteBoxActive = false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    var cookie = new HttpCookie(cookieName, "1")
                    {
                        HttpOnly = true,
                        Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1),
                        Secure = false
                    };

                    HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
                    ViewBag.IsWhiteBoxActive = true;
                }

                model.WhiteBox = whiteBox;
            }

            return model;
        }
```